# Передать в контроллер параметр через Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть представление с такой ссылкой :

```
<a href="#" onclick="DelSumm('@item.Id', '@item.Title')" style="cursor:pointer">Удалить</a>
```

Есть скрипт, который без проблем принимает переметры :

```
 function DelSumm(id, title) {

        var result = confirm("Вы действительно хотите удалить " + title + "?");
        if (result == true) {
            $.ajax(
                url = '/User/Delete_Summary', data = "1111"
            );
        }
    }
```

И есть метод контроллера, к которому Ajax обращается :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete_Summary(string id)
 {
   // что то делаем
 }
```

На входе `id` всегда null - в чем дело ?

UPD Итоговая разметка в браузере:

```
<a href="#" onclick="DelSumm('a3670f1b-f0ef-4c80-a9ea-89a47e444b4f', 'Должность')" style="cursor:pointer">Удалить</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url: '/User/Delete_Summary/' + encodeURIComponent(id)
```

или

```
url: '/User/Delete_Summary',
data: { id: id }
```

Полностью:

```
function DelSumm(id, title) {

    var result = confirm("Вы действительно хотите удалить " + title + "?");
    if (result == true) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/User/Delete_Summary',
            data: { id: id }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Для второго варианта с `data`  входным параметром должен быть конечно не string ?

Comment: @Сергей Отчего же? `string` сработает.

Comment: тогда возникает совсем не понятная ошибка : `DelSumm is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick`

Comment: @Сергей посмотрите в браузере, как выглядит сгенеренный html для анкера - добавьте это, пожалуйста, в вопрос.

Comment: не совсем понял про анкера но html ссылки добавил

Comment: @Сергей Отставить :). Проверьте код функции `DelSumm` и содержимое консоли браузера после загрузки страницы - похоже на ошибку парсера.

Comment: В консоли вот такая ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @Сергей Где-то синтаксическая ошибка в javascript-e - должен быть еще указан номер строки.

Comment: Показывает 72 строку, хотя всего во вьюхе 60.

Comment: @Сергей Это строка сгенеренного html. Движок браузера ничего не знает про вью. Внимательно сравните Ваш и мой варианты функции `DelSumm`.

Comment: Я скопировал ваш код и получил ту же ошибку

Comment: @Сергей Найдите 72-ую строку в html коде страницы, используя "View page source" браузера.

Comment: Подчеркивает  `url: '/User/Delete_Summary'`

Comment: @Сергей "У старого наблюдателя от постоянного наблюдения глаз как бы замыливался, он чего и не было - видел." Володя Шарапов. *исправил :)*

Comment: "Вот оно что Михалыч!"  Иван Дулин

Comment: Смотрел на ошибку пол часа и не увидел, а она даже не пряталась.) Спасибо!